# Erase character with BackSpace on a bash command line

Tags: bash, command-line, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a configuration for bash and profile files, but I copied that file to other server so now I can't erase text only by pushing backspace, I need to press Shift + Backspace to erase text.

What is the parameter I need to change to restore it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally (depending on the *conventions* for the particular system you are using), the <kbd>*backspace*</kbd> key sends either ASCII BS (`^H`) and DEL (`^?`)

Some terminal emulators switch between ASCII BS (`^H`) and DEL (`^?`) when you use the shift-modifier.  Some do not.  Apparently the program you are using for ssh does not.

Given this line from your `.profile`:

```
stty erase "^H" kill "^U" intr "^C" eof "^D" susp "^Z"
```

it seems that your terminal normally sends `^?` (ASCII DEL), but you told it to expect `^H` (ASCII BS).  However, your terminal switches to `^H` when you modify <kbd>*backspace*</kbd> with the <kbd>*shift*</kbd> key.  You could have used

```
stty erase "^?" kill "^U" intr "^C" eof "^D" susp "^Z"
```

and gotten better results.

Comment: Hi Thomas

I have this (^?),  but that's strange because before I copied the profile files, Work normally, but when I run source.profile changes that backspace erase.

also the program is the same for both servers.

Comment: You didn't give any details on the contents of your files, the answer addressed the limited information which was given.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/SVd1KJYk <-- Bashrc

Comment: http://pastebin.com/D92zNzkK <-- profile

Comment: Do you know if this apply same for SQLPLUS, always when i am inside the db i need to erase also with Shift...

Comment: I'm not certain, but a quick search hints that sqlplus uses the `stty erase` setting, and if you update your `.profile` to match the terminal settings (or the terminal to match `.profile`), then sqlplus will "work".

Comment: I am unable to assing both `ctrl-h` and backspace together. Like if `ctrl-h` works backspace returns `^?`

Comment: if we are using `zsh`, should we have `stty erase "^H" kill "^U" intr "^C" eof "^D" susp "^Z"` in `.zprofile` or can we have it in `.zshrc`?

Answer (score 2):

I get the feeling there isn't a one-size-fits-all solution.  The following fixed the issue in bash 4.1 in gnome-terminal (2.31.3) for me:

```
stty sane
```

Ref: [Source](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO-5.html)

Comment: This is the best advice. The top answer's fearsome line of multiple `stty` overrides is totally unnecessary in all but a few (read: _severly broken_) cases.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that the terminfo data is missing. This happened to me while working with chroot. This [forum post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1671529#p1671529) helped me figure that out, and I couldn't find a valid reference on Stackexchange for something like it, so here you go.

> It was enough to copy the directory /usr/share/terminfo/ to
>   /usr/share/terminfo of chroot directory.